# Evaluate $\left(\mbox{L}\right)\int_{0}^{1}\,\mathrm{ g}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

> Let
>   $\,\mathrm{g}\left(x\right) =
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rl}
> \,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\,,      & x \in \mathbb{Q}
> \\[1mm]
> -\,\mathrm{f}^{2}\left(x\right)\,, & x \not\in \mathbb{Q}
> \end{array}\right.
> \quad$
>   where $\,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)$  continuous at $\left[0,1\right]$. Find a formula to
>   
>   evaluate
>   $\displaystyle{\left(\mbox{L}\right)\int_{0}^{1}\,\mathrm{g}\left(x\right)
> \,\mathrm{d}x}$ and find $\left(\mbox{L}\right)$ for
>   $\,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) = \,\sqrt[3]{\, x\,}\,$.

$\left(\mbox{L}\right)$ denotes Lebesgue-integral.

I don't even know how to start, this is for exam I have on Tuesday.

I'm not familiar with Lebesgue-integral, can you help me please ?.

Comment: $g$ equal a.e. to $-f^2$.

Comment: Yes,I edited @ArcticChar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lebesgue integral doesn't care about sets of measure zero. So, you can change $g$ to whatever you want on $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ (in particular, the natural choice is $-f^2(x)$) and still get the same value.

So, your integral is equal to $\int_0^1 -f^2$, which you can easily evaluate.

Comment: In particular ,countable sets, like Q, are measure-zero sets. +1